# Bitcoin core does not produce a wallet at all

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, address-generation

I'm reading tutorials on working with bitcoin core like this:

- http://bitcoindaily.org/bitcoin-guides/bitcoin-core-tutorial/
  and
- http://bitcoindaily.org/bitcoin-guides/how-to-recover-bitcoins-bitcoin-core-wont-sync-export-private-key/

Both of which suggest the use of bitcoin core should produce a wallet address of some kind automatically.  Specifically, the second says:

> Bitcoin core automatically generates your first bitcoin address for
>   you but you can create as many new ones as you want.

I can't seem to get a wallet address to get started.

Where there is supposed to be a wallet address there is none, and I am asked to enter one, but how do I get one in the first place?

Here is what I see:

[image]

There is no address, and I can't just guess one---anything I type in the Address box says it is invalid.

Comment: You need to click on receive to create an address to receive coins on. The send tab is for sending to others.

Answer (score 1):

> Bitcoin core automatically generates your first bitcoin address for you but you can create as many new ones as you want.

This is outdated. An address is no longer created for you by default.

You can create an address from within the Receive tab by clicking the "Create new receiving address" button.

> Here is what I see:

You are looking at the Sending Addresses window which is for addresses that you want to send to. It is not for your own receiving addresses; that would be the Receiving Addresses window. In recent versions of Bitcoin Core, the functionality to create a new address in the Receiving Addresses window has been removed.

Comment: When I create a receiving address, I can't use it for sending, signing, etc.  I'm looking for the ability to sign a json object message for development purposes, and when I use the receiving address, it tells me this is invalid for sending.

Comment: "Invalid for sending"? Have you received funds to send? As far as signing messages goes, that functionality isn't supported for segwit addresses (which you'll create by default).